# Flutter - TextField in StatefulBuilder in modalBottomSheet not working

Tags: flutter, keyboard, textfield, stateful, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet

I have a problem. In my code, I call `showModalBottomSheet` and inside of it, I have a feedback form. The user can select a reaction and then leave a comment to submit.

Therefore, I had to use a `StatefulBuilder` to use `setState` inside the modal. The `TextField` has a weird behavior though—when I click on it, the keyboard appears for an instant and then the modal is reset to the original state. If I remove the `StatefulBuilder` and I leave the `GestureDetector` as main Widget, everything works as expected (the keyboard appears, the modal moves to show it, and so on).

Is there any way to make the `StatefulBuilder` and the `TextField` coexist? Below there is a snippet of code, appropriately cut to focus on this problem.

```
TextEditingController feedbackTextFieldController = TextEditingController();

...

showModalBottomSheet<void>(
    context: context,
    isScrollControlled: true, // makes content maxHeight = full device height
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      bool _isFeedbackLoading = false;

      return StatefulBuilder(
        builder: (context, setState) => GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            // the following is needed to dismiss the keyboard on tap outside of it
            FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);

            if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
              currentFocus.unfocus();
            }
          },
          child: AnimatedPadding(
            // to make the modal move when the keyboard is shown
            padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets,
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
            curve: Curves.decelerate,
            child: Container(
              child: _isFeedbackLoading
                  ? Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    )
                  : TextField(
                      controller: feedbackTextFieldController,
                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                      textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
                      maxLines: 2,
                      style: ...,
                      decoration: ...,
                    ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  );
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can give try to following code

```dart
showModalBottomSheet<void>(
    context: context,
    isScrollControlled: true, // makes content maxHeight = full device height
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      bool _isFeedbackLoading = false;

      return StatefulBuilder(
        // it could also because of you may reaching the wrong context
        // builder: (context, setState) => GestureDetector(
        builder: (_, setState) => GestureDetector(
          // may be you are not able to tap
          behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
          onTap: () {
            // the following is needed to dismiss the keyboard on tap outside of it
            FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);

            if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
              currentFocus.unfocus();
            }
          },
          child: AnimatedPadding(
            // to make the modal move when the keyboard is shown
            padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets,
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
            curve: Curves.decelerate,
            child: Container(
              child: _isFeedbackLoading
                  ? Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    )
                  : TextField(
                      controller: feedbackTextFieldController,
                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                      textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
                      maxLines: 2,
                      style: ...,
                      decoration: ...,
                    ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  );
```

or you can try to make it another `StatefulWidget` for this, like following

```dart
showModalBottomSheet<void>(
    context: context,
    isScrollControlled: true, // makes content maxHeight = full device height
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return YourRefactoredStatefulWidget();
    }
.....
```

Comment: The first solution didn't work, but by creating a dedicated `StatefulWidget` I was able to solve the issue! Thank you very much!